# terminal shows percent sign at the end of the path

Tags: mac, terminal

Since today, my terminal shows a percent sign (%) at the end of the path.

what is this and why this happens?

Is it means a special thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on Mac , so since `catalina` the default shell for user is now `zsh` instead of `bash` .